# An HTMLInputElement gets clicked, and an HTMLOptionElement gets

Tags: html, vba, html-select

I'm am trying to write vba code to fill out web-forms and click buttons for me. I am looping through the various `option` tags on the page to select the one I want. When I reach it, I want to select it, but I'm not sure of the syntax.

```
Dim htmlO As HTMLOptionElement
For Each htmlO In Object.getElementByTagName("option")
    If Trim(htmlO.value) = "INS" Then
       htmlO.????  (click? select?)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Here is the HTML from the webpage:

```
<select gtbfieldid="40" id="menu" name="pv_choice">
<option selected="selected" value="ZZZ">Choose Menu Option
</option><option value="BL_COMP">Blanket Companies
</option><option value="CARR_SEARCH">Carrier Search
</option><option value="PASSWORD">Change Password
</option><option value="FED_REG">FMCSA Register
</option><option value="FEEDBACK">Feedback
</option><option value="HOME">Home Page
</option><option value="INS">Insurance Filing
</option><option value="OOS_LIST">Out Of Service Carriers
</option></select>
```

I want to select the option "INS".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked in the end was...

> Dim htmlO As HTMLSelectElement
>   Set htmlS = objdoc.getElementById("menu")
>   htmlS.selectedIndex = 7

I had to reference the entire menu and choose which one to select, not select the individual option.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim StrFindText  as string
Dim htmlSelect As HTMLSelectElement
Dim htmlItemOption As IHTMLOptionElement

Set htmlSelect  = Object.getElementById("menu")
StrFindText = "INS"

For i = 0 To htmlSelect.options.length - 1
    htmlItemOption = htmlSelect.options(i)
    ' UCase(htmlItemOption.text) = UCase(StrFindText) ' if find text options
    If UCase(htmlItemOption.value) = UCase(StrFindText) Then
       htmlItemOption.selected = True
       Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used VBA so I apologize in advance but assuming it uses the same structure for the DOM than other languages I'm familiar with, try:

```
htmlO.selected= "selected"
```

which is how I would achieve this in javascript :)

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your answer...but it doesn't work. The menu option does not get selected when I do htmlO.check.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a doofus, I thought you were working with check boxes. Try selected="selected"

Updated in my original response.

Comment: I tried htmlO.select also and it didn't work...thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

**CSS selector:**

Here is a much simpler way. Use a CSS selector of `option[value='INS']`.
This says select element with `option` tag that has attribute `value` whose value is `'INS'`.

---

**CSS query:**

[image: query]

---

**VBA:**

The [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) is applied via the [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method of `document`.

```
objdoc.querySelector("option[value='INS']").Click
```

or

```
objdoc.querySelector("option[value='INS']").Selected = True
```